# Google Play Store crashes when loading an Instant App

Tags: instant-apps

I'm not too concerned about this issue because I've been downloading apps since I had an Android, but I was wondering what instant apps was like when I saw it.

I turn off a lot of permissions and disable lots of built-in apps out of blunt rage and have to factory reset my phone later when I can't fix the problem. I did that not too long ago and instant apps doesn't work (this was the first time I tried to use it). I don't feel like factory resetting. I use a Samsung Galaxy J7 Prime.

I don't know how to attach the video that shows it so I will leave an image:

[image]